# MUI TablePagination Component Causing Hydration Error in Next.js 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I'm getting a hydration error in Next.js 13 when using the MUI TablePagination component.

The error looks like this

> Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
>
> Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <td> in <div>.

I couldn't find anything online about this.

Any clue how to get around this?